# I need to compare an individual object to an array using a method in a separate class

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, class, object

```
int blue = 1;
int yellow = 2;
int green = 3;
int pink = 4;        

Triangle[ ] tri = new Triangle[21];
Triangle[0] tri = new Triangle [blue,yellow,green];
Triangle[1] tri= new Triangle [pink,blue,yellow];
Triangle[2] tri= new Triangle [green,pink,yellow];
```

I have this array and i want to compare the objects in to each other using a method in a separate class

```
public boolean compareColors(Triangle another)
{
  if(colorRight == getRightColor() && colorLeft == getLeftColor() && colorBottom == getBottomColor())
      return true;
  else
      return false;
}
```

I can't figure out the exact way to compare them or use the Triangle another input to compare the triangles one by one

Comment: `new Triangle [blue,yellow,green];` isn't valid syntax...

Comment: If I had to guess I would say you mean new Triangle(blue, yellow, green);

Comment: Are you sure your `compareColors` is in another class? If so, maybe it is better to implement the `Comparator` interface.

Answer (score 0):

Once you fix your syntax issues you would be able to do something like:

```
if (tri[0].compareColors(tri[1])) {
  System.out.println("tri[0] and tri[1] have the same colors.");
}
```

For this to be true you would set things up as follows:

```
Triangle[] tri = new Triangle[3];
tri[0] = new Triangle(blue, yellow, green);
tri[1] = new Triangle(blue, yellow, green);
tri[2] = new Triangle(green ,pink, yellow);
```

Your compareColors method can also be simplified:

```
public boolean compareColors(Triangle another) {
  return colorRight == another.getRightColor() 
      && colorLeft == another.getLeftColor() 
      && colorBottom == another.getBottomColor();
}
```

However, typically we write this as:

```
public boolean compareColors(Triangle another) {
  return this.colorRight == another.colorRight
      && this.colorLeft == another.colorLeft
      && this.colorBottom == another.colorBottom;
}
```

Comment: its says that tri[0] tri = new Triangle(blue, yellow, green); is not a statement

Comment: should be 
tri[0] = new Triangle(blue, yellow, green); the array elements cannot be given a variable name.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample `Triangle` class with a little tweak, enums.
Instead of representing your color with `int` you use an enumeration type:

```
public class Triangle
{
    public enum Color { BLUE, YELLOW, GREEN, PINK };

    private Color colorLeft;
    private Color colorRight;
    private Color colorBottom;

    public Triangle(Color colorLeft, Color colorRight, Color colorBottom)
    {
        this.colorLeft = colorLeft;
        this.colorRight = colorRight;
        this.colorBottom = colorBottom;
    }

    public boolean compareColors(Triangle another)
    {
        return this.colorRight == another.colorRight
                && this.colorLeft == another.colorLeft
                && this.colorBottom == another.colorBottom;
    }
}
```

It is more robust and natural than using `int`.
You can then create your triangles following this example:

```
Triangle t = new Triangle(Color.PINK, Color.BLUE, Color.YELLOW);
```

If your wish to keep using `int` for now, you can still use this class to guide you.